# Outbox pattern with kafka and mongoDB connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, mongodb-kafka-connector

I want to implement **Outbox Pattern** in our microservices using **Mongo-Kafka connector**, in my outbox(a MongoDB collection) I store topic data using these fields:
`kafka_topic`, `kafka_key`, `kafka_value`, `kafka_header_keys`, `kafka_header_values`.

But how should I config mongo-kafka connector to dynamically choose the topic from the `kafka_topic` field and also its values and headers from other outbox fields?
I can not find settings to do this from its config reference.

I'm also thinking about getting a fork from mongo-kafka connector repository and extend it with my custom implementation.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got my answer, mongo-kafka connector does not support the outbox pattern.
for other databases, Debezium has the [Outbox event router](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/outbox-event-router.html) which does that for us, but it does not support the MongoDB connector until writing this answer.

As a final answer: we forked the mongo-kafka connector and implemented our outbox pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I made a PR for [the Outbox Event Router for MongoDB feature](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/pull/2877) and it was just merged yesterday! (2021.11.17). So, I believe this feature would be applied in the near future.
It supports same features with the existing Outbox Event Router.
But, you would have to use multi-document transaction yet. But, it's planned to be developed in the future without multi-document transaction.